# Replace all that not contains .. ER

Tags: php, regex, arrays, indexing, preg-replace

Hey guys, how i can replace all index of array that not contains quant in index name ?
i trying this:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $query ); ++$i ){
          foreach( $query[$i] as $index => $data ){
               echo preg_replace( '/(?!quant(.*)$)/', '', $index ), '<br />';
          }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "replace [an] index of [an] array?"

Comment: replace all index of not contains 'quant' in index name

Comment: Since you have problems explaining it, please just provide an example.

Comment: Array(
 
 [quant1] => ...
 [price1] => ...
 [quant2] => ...
 [price2] => ...
)

Comment: Replace all of not contains 'quant' in index to null

Comment: Remove the element entirely or set its value to `null`?

Comment: Also provide an example of what the corresponding output should be.

Comment: Array( [quant1] => ... [price1] => ... [quant2] => ... [price2] => ... ) i need return: Array( [quant1] => ...  [quant2] => ... )

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like all you want is indexes filtered which do not contain `"quant"`. If so then a simple `if` will do, and there's no need for a regex or any string manipulation whatsoever:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count( $query ); ++$i) {
    foreach ($query[$i] as $index => $data) {
        if (strstr($index, "quant")) {
            echo $index, '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlikely for the example you've shown. I'd recommend that you update your question with an exact printout of input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this php code to do this filtering:

```
$array = array("quant1"=>1, "price1"=>2, "quant2"=>3, "price2"=>4, "quant3"=>3);
$filteredKeys = array_filter(array_keys($array), function ($elem) { return strpos($elem, "quant") !== false; } );
print_r(array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($filteredKeys)));
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [quant1] => 1
    [quant2] => 3
    [quant3] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the regex you were looking for:

```
^(?:(?!quant).)+)$
```

The idea is to apply the lookahead at each position before you consume the next character. Here's another option:

```
^(?!.*quant).+$
```

Here the lookahead is applied only once, at the beginning of the string.  Starting there, it scans the whole string looking for an instance of `quant`.  If it doesn't find one, the lookahead succeeds, and `.+$` goes ahead and gobbles up the whole string.

EDIT: Also notice the start anchor (`^`) I added.  Whatever regex you eventually use, it **must** be anchored at both ends.  Otherwise you'll never be sure you really examined the whole string.